# Asp.net Core + IIS 8.5 : The view 'Index' was not found

Tags: asp.net, view, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-8.5

Deployed App on IIS 8.5, Asp.net core

3 apps, Front-end, API and Login (on the same site);

All 3 are working PERFECTLY in IIS express from VS2015;

The front-end (only html/AngularJS) & API are working perfectly on IIS 8.5

But for the Login (IdentityServer4):

```
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
 - ~/UI/Home/Views/Index.cshtml
 - ~/UI/SharedViews/Index.cshtml
```

I understand that '~/' refers to the approot;

My VS2015 structure:
[image: Visual Studio 2015 project structure]

Tested/Checked:

- .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) in Program.cs
- All privileges to IIS_IUSRS user account on the server
- CustomViewLocationExpander :

  ```
  public class CustomViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander {

     public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations){
         yield return "~/UI/{1}/Views/{0}.cshtml";
         yield return "~/UI/SharedViews/{0}.cshtml";
     }

     public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
     {
     }
  }
  ```

I can access all content freely on 'wwwroot' only js/images/css

I'm clueless on this one.

Comment: Did you check if you deployed the views? Can you share how your project.json looks like?

Comment: I forgot to add the "UI" folder aside the "wwwroot" in the publishOptions element in the project.json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I searched for more than an hour before posting. Took a break and found this :

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/issues/23

add "UI" to the publish options in project.json

```
"publishOptions": {
  "include": [
    "wwwroot",
    "UI",
    "YourCertificateName.pfx",
    "web.config"
 ]}
```

Precision : "UI" Refers to the 'root' folder containing my views. You have to include them all (root view folders) in "publishOptions" to be exported.

Comment: I'm sorry for the useless and bad edit. Too many hours of coding, I think my brain was about to turn off last night... Thanks for your answer anyway

Comment: I know you said this, but I didn't understand what you meant. Note that "UI" refers to the name of the folder that contains the views. Mine was called "Views" so adding "UI" to my publishOptions didn't work :-p